# ASP.NET GridView SortedAscendingHeaderStyle does not work

Tags: asp.net, gridview

My `SortedAscendingHeaderStyle` and `SortedDescendingHeaderStyle` is not working at all

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdProducts" runat="server" CssClass="grid" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" PageSize="100" EmptyDataText="No data to show"
              onrowdatabound="grdProducts_RowDataBound"  onrowediting="grdProducts_RowEditing" onsorting="grdProducts_Sorting" AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
  <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="even" />
  <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle ForeColor="White" CssClass="sorted" />
  <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sorted desc" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Rows are sorted correctly when headers are clicked, but when I inspect the header using FireBug, it only shows: (this is when sorted ascending)

```
<th scope="col">
  <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$body$ctl00$grdProducts','Sort$Namekey')">Namekey</a>
</th>
```

ForeColor and CssClass are not set at all.

Anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: My C# code behind

```
  protected void grdProducts_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
  {
    if ((string)ViewState["SortColumn"] == e.SortExpression)
      ViewState["SortDirection"] = ((string)ViewState["SortDirection"] == "") ? " DESC" : "";
    else
    {
      ViewState["SortColumn"] = e.SortExpression;
      ViewState["SortDirection"] = "";
    }
  }

  protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
  {
    BindGrid();
    base.OnPreRender(e);
  }

  private void BindGrid()
  {
    string query = "SELECT ... ORDER BY " + ViewState["SortColumn"] + ViewState["SortDirection"];

    DataTable dt = SqlFunctions.Select(query);
    grdProducts.DataSource = dt;
    grdProducts.DataBind();
  }
```

Comment: Silly question, what happens if you do a hard refresh Ctl+F5?

Comment: Firefox asks if I want to "Resend", I clicked it, then the column is still sorted, and the header still has no class/style.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure if **SortedDescendingHeaderStyle** works without code if you're not using an `asp:SQLDataSource` as your GridView data source. But a little coding can get you there.

You need to apply the CSS style manually to the header cell. You can do it in the Sorting event.

```
protected void grdProducts_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
   if ((string)ViewState["SortColumn"] == e.SortExpression)
   {
      ViewState["SortDirection"] = ((string)ViewState["SortDirection"] == "") ? " DESC" : "";
      grdProducts.HeaderRow.Cells[GetColumnIndex( e.SortExpression )].CssClass = "AscendingHeaderStyle";
   }
   else
   {
      ViewState["SortColumn"] = e.SortExpression;
      ViewState["SortDirection"] = "";
      grdProducts.HeaderRow.Cells[GetColumnIndex( e.SortExpression )].CssClass = "DescendingHeaderStyle";
   }
   BindGrid();
}




private int GetColumnIndex( string SortExpression )
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach( DataControlField c in gvwCustomers.Columns )
    {
        if( c.SortExpression == SortExpression )
            break;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work:-( When I call gridview.DataBind(), CSS disappears again.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have enough rep to comment on the accepted answer. When I tried applying the solution, it would sort properly, but did not apply the CSS class to what was eventually rendered.

In my case, invoking DataBind() on my grid AFTER sorting my DataSource (List) and assigning it as the grid's DataSource, but BEFORE setting the CssClass did the trick. Figured I'd share in case someone else encountered something similar.

Comment: Do you mean that in the `_Sorting` event handler you called `DataBind()` and then assigned the `CssClass` to the sorting asc/desc style properties? I am trying to use the styles, but they do not seem to be applied at all.

Comment: Your solution works. The process should be 1) assign the sorted data source to the grid; 2) call DataBind(); 3) assign ascending/descending class to CssClass to the header row cell of the sorted column. This solution is not using

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the timing of your databinding.  Change your databinding to work like this:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {    
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();      
    }
  }

  protected void grdProducts_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
  {
    if ((string)ViewState["SortColumn"] == e.SortExpression)
      ViewState["SortDirection"] = ((string)ViewState["SortDirection"] == "") ? " DESC" : "";
    else
    {
      ViewState["SortColumn"] = e.SortExpression;
      ViewState["SortDirection"] = "";
    }
    BindGrid();
  }
```

[GridView.Sorting Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Super-late, but for reference. It works for me, using the following:

Here's my code (in x.aspx):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceX" runat="server" ConnectionString="xxx"
    EnableViewState="False" OnSelecting="SqlDataSourceXSelecting"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ....
    AllowSorting="True"
    EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="False"
    OnSorted="GridViewResults_OnSorted" ....           DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceX" CssClass="table table-bordered text-left">
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="SortedAscendingHeaderStyle"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="SortedDescendingHeaderStyle"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
    <Columns>
```

...

Here's my code (in x.aspx.cs):

```
protected void GridViewResults_OnSorted(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   ExecuteSearch(); //Adds some where clauses to the SQL Data Source, no explicit sorting here
}
```

This then creates the following table headers, after clicking for sort:

```
<th class="SortedDescendingHeaderStyle" scope="col">
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridViewResults','Sort$LocalUnitId')">BUR Nummer</a>
</th>
```