# ASP.NET 4 GridView doesn't show arrows when sorting and binded with generic List<T>

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview

My question is: How to make GridView show arrows when sorting and binded with generic List?

I've being testing the new properties in ASP.NET to show arrows when sorting in a GridView following this blog entry http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scothu/archive/2010/08/28/gridview-with-sort-arrows-and-showing-header-when-empty.aspx.

My aspx markup is like so

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" CssClass="gridView"
...
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" CssClass="SortedAscending" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" CssClass="SortedDescending" />
...
</asp:GridView>
```

It works fine for me when GridView is binded with a SqlDataSource or DataSet and I've seen in articles that ObjectDataSource works well too. It generates something like the following HTML markup.

```
 &lt;th style="background-color: rgb(109, 149, 225);" scope="col" class="SortedAscending"&gt;&lt;a style="color: White;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView3','Sort$Name')"&gt;Name&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/th&gt;
```

The important thing I see here is `class="SortedAscending"`. That's the name I gave to the `SortedAscendingHeaderStyle` attribute of the aspx page.

My problem is that my BLLs return `generic List<T>` and when I bind those to GridView, it generates something like the following HTML markup.

```
&lt;th scope="col"&gt;&lt;a style="color: White;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView2','Sort$Name')"&gt;Name&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/th&gt;
```

In this markup, I'm missing `class="SortedAscending"` and that's why I'm having trouble getting arrows in my GridView.

Comment: To be clear:  
1. Do you have the sorting actually working?  
2. Are you just trying to get the header displaying correctly?

Comment: @mjwills: sorting header works but arrows are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Check here [Stack Overflow Q.10304546](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10304546/623583). This technique may help you get the arrows to display in your column headers.