# Was anyone successful using the GridView.SortAscendingHeaderStyle property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

Using .NET 4.0 framework, I tried to set some properties of a `GridView` bound to an `SqlDataSource` to apply styles to the sorted columns. But no matter what `BackColor, ForeColor, CssClass` I used, when viewing the source of the rendered page, the resulting `<table>` did not have any classes or styles applied to the headers (or cells). It seemed that any changes to the `SortAscendingHeaderStyle` or `SortDescendingHeaderStyle` properties were ignored by the grid view control.

Besides allowing sorting, do any other properties need to be assigned certain values for the `SortAscendingHeaderStyle` or `SortDescendingHeaderStyle` to work? Or do any events need to be handled?

I simply want some change, just to see that a column has been sorted - no matter what change (color, border, font - does not matter) and that is not happening.

Besides `AllowPaging` and `AllowSorting` set to `True`, I set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False` and the rest of the `GridView` properties are at their default values.

EDIT:

After reading Microsoft help on `GridView.SortedAscendingHeaderStyle Property` my brain seriously hurts. They start off with:

> Gets **or sets** the CSS style to apply to a GridView column heading when
>   the column is sorted in ascending order.

then proceed to give the following syntax:

```
Public ReadOnly Property SortedAscendingHeaderStyle As TableItemStyle
```

which already contraditcts the bold part of the first line. It is getting worse:

> **true** if a style is applied to the GridView heading when the column is
>   sorted in ascending order; otherwise, **false**.

It does not bother the author, that the property is an object of `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableItemStyle` class, and not just a `boolean` which can be `true` or `false`. Or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many unsuccessul attempts to find out why the properties had no effect, I used the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10304546/2721750

As pointed out by https://stackoverflow.com/a/23894428/2721750 the order of applying styles is important.

The combination of both solution works. The process should be

1. assign the sorted data source to the grid;

   call DataBind();

   assign ascending/descending class to CssClass to the header row cell of the sorted column.

```
private int GetColumnIndex(GridView grv, string SortExpression)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataControlField c in grv.Columns)
    {
        if (c.SortExpression == SortExpression)
            break;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

protected void grvSampleOrders_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    Utility_Web.PersistSortDirection(Session, (((Control)sender)).ID, e.SortExpression, e.SortDirection);

    grvSampleOrders.DataSource = Utility_Web.GetSortedDataView(Session, dsSampleOrders, (((Control)sender)).ID); // replace original SQL data source with its sorted copy
    grvSampleOrders.DataBind();
    grvSampleOrders.HeaderRow.Cells[GetColumnIndex(grvSampleOrders, e.SortExpression)].CssClass = Session["grvSampleOrders_sort"].ToString().Equals("ASC") ? "sortasc" : "sortdesc";
}
```

To invite the answers, I will not be accepting my answer for some time, as it only offers a workaround.